# Is it better to set rules in ip6tables or disable ipv6?

Tags: iptables, ipv6

I have the following network configuration:

```
# ifconfig -a
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:e0:1c:73:02:09
          inet addr:10.1.4.41  Bcast:10.1.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::2e0:4cff:fe75:309/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:858600 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1069549 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:5 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:142871181 (136.2 MiB)  TX bytes:717982640 (684.7 MiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:37952 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:37952 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:3396918 (3.2 MiB)  TX bytes:3396918 (3.2 MiB)
```

I have DHCP server in my network and I can get the following lease:

```
lease {
  interface "eth0";
  fixed-address 10.1.4.41;
  option subnet-mask 255.255.0.0;
  option routers 10.1.255.253;
  option dhcp-lease-time 120;
  option dhcp-message-type 5;
  option domain-name-servers 82.160.125.52,213.199.198.248,82.160.1.1;
  option dhcp-server-identifier 192.168.22.22;
  renew 3 2014/01/01 18:34:41;
  rebind 3 2014/01/01 18:35:30;
  expire 3 2014/01/01 18:35:45;
}
```

I can ping `127.0.0.1`, `::1`, `10.1.4.41`:

```
$ ping 10.1.4.41
PING 10.1.4.41 (10.1.4.41) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.1.4.41: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.065 ms
64 bytes from 10.1.4.41: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.075 ms
64 bytes from 10.1.4.41: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.085 ms
^C
--- 10.1.4.41 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2000ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.065/0.075/0.085/0.008 ms

$ ping 127.0.0.1
PING 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.066 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.056 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.055 ms
^C
--- 127.0.0.1 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 1999ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.055/0.059/0.066/0.005 ms

$ ping6 ::1
PING ::1(::1) 56 data bytes
64 bytes from ::1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.052 ms
64 bytes from ::1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.049 ms
64 bytes from ::1: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.037 ms
^C
--- ::1 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 1998ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.037/0.046/0.052/0.006 ms
```

I can't ping the ipv6 address `fe80::2e0:4cff:fe75:309`:

```
$ ping6 fe80::2e0:4cff:fe75:309
connect: Invalid argument
```

I have set some iptables rules (ipv4):

```
# iptables -S
-P INPUT DROP
-P FORWARD DROP
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-N TCP
-N UDP
-A INPUT -i eth0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i tun0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j DROP
-A INPUT -p udp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j UDP
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK SYN -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j TCP
-A INPUT -p tcp -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset
-A INPUT -p udp -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-proto-unreachable
-A OUTPUT -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j DROP
```

And it works as expected for ipv4. But when I check ip6tables, I can see some packets go there:

```
# ip6tables -nvL
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 381 packets, 27624 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 390 packets, 26296 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

I followed [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Simple_Stateful_Firewall) guide, and they say that I should copy the iptables (ipv4) configuration and paste it in ip6tables (ipv6). But when I do this, no packet can go through the rule `RELATED,ESTABLISHED` in the ipv6 table. All of them are dropped because of INPUT chain policy (`DROP`).

```
# ip6tables -nvL
Chain INPUT (policy DROP 5 packets, 360 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 ACCEPT     all      eth0   *       ::/0                 ::/0                 ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 ACCEPT     all      lo     *       ::/0                 ::/0
    0     0 ACCEPT     all      tun0   *       ::/0                 ::/0                 ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 DROP       all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 ctstate INVALID
    0     0 UDP        udp      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 ctstate NEW
    0     0 TCP        tcp      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 tcp flags:0x17/0x02 ctstate NEW
    0     0 REJECT     tcp      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 reject-with tcp-reset
    0     0 REJECT     udp      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 reject-with icmp6-port-unreachable

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 DROP       all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 ctstate INVALID

Chain TCP (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain UDP (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

As you can see there's no output packets, so why google and stack exchange try to connect to my machine? And how do they do it because even I can't ping my ipv6 address?

They also say if my ISP doesn't have ipv6 (in the lease, there's no ipv6 entry) I should disable ipv6 and had done this before by using `ipv6.disable=1`. I asked similar question at `meta.stackoverflow.com`, and I got an answer that I shouldn't disable ipv6.

I have no idea what to do. I have some connection problems, I mean sometimes I can't access pages at stack exchange, or google, I have also problems with pastebin.com. In each case there are the same symptoms -- after typing an address in my browser, I have to wait sometimes several minutes in order to access the site and after reloading it 2-3 times, I can browse it freely, at least for a certain period of time.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your IPv6 address starts with `fe80:` and is therefore a link-local address. Such addresses are only usable on the same link as the network interface. Because the same link-local subnet exists on every network interface you'll have to specify *which* interface you want to use. For example when you want to ping a link-local address.

Try one of the following `ping6` examples. Both do the same:

```
ping6 fe80::2e0:4cff:fe75:309%eth0
ping6 -I eth0 fe80::2e0:4cff:fe75:309
```

This also means that only systems on your local link (your LAN) can use this link-local address to connect to your system. Routers won't route those addresses. There is no way that Google or Stack Exchange are sending IPv6 traffic to your machine, because your machine does not have an IPv6 address that is reachable/routable from them.

So, what IPv6 traffic *are* you seeing on your interface? Probably things like mDNS ([multicast DNS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast_DNS)) and other protocols that can automatically connect on the local link. For example [Apple Airplay](http://www.apple.com/airplay/) and [Windows Home Group](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows7/products/features/homegroup).

Your firewall rules are missing a very important thing: `ICMPv6`. IPv6 uses ICMP a lot more than IPv4, and not letting ICMP packets in can severely cripple your traffic because you won't receive error messages related to that traffic. This can cause long delays/timeouts. Allowing ICMPv6 traffic in usually doesn't hurt, so you can add this to your firewall rules:

```
ip6tables -A INPUT -p icmpv6 -j ACCEPT
```

If you want to block `ping6` packets (although I don't really understand why people still do that these days, it makes debugging connectivity a lot harder) you can add this like before the previous `ACCEPT` line:

```
ip6tables -A INPUT -p icmpv6 --icmpv6-type 128 -j DROP
```

This is mostly important when you get real global IPv6 connectivity to your machine, but it won't hurt if you already prepare for that :-)

Comment: I get it now. I added the `icmpv6` rule but limited to 20/min, and I can see that packets go there. `ping6 -I eth0 fe80::2e0:4cff:fe75:309` also works.

Answer (score 5):

I always take the position, when managing systems, that anything that I don't *explicitly* need to provide the services on said system, that it should be turned off. This philosophy goes to everything whether it's:

- un-installing unnecessary software
- disabling a GUI desktop on a server
- disabling and/or excluding uncessary hardware
- disabling IPv6
- disabling uncessary services
- etc.

Comment: I have the same philosophy, but in this case I really don't know what to do. Some people say that I should disable ipv6, others say something different. I have problems even when ipv6 is disabled.

Comment: @MikhailMorfikov - does your ISP perform any proxy/NAT where they're making their customers use IPv6 just to access into the ISP. I don't think this is an issue for you, otherwise you'd have an IPv6 address but just thought of it.

Comment: I have no idea, perhaps I should ask them, and maybe they will do something and fix the problem.

Answer (score 3):

> They also say if my ISP doesn't have ipv6 (in the lease, there's no ipv6 entry) I should disable ipv6 and had done this before by using ipv6.disable=1. I asked similar question at meta.stackoverflow.com, and I got an answer that I shouldn't disable ipv6.

of course you would not see an IPv6 address lease with DHCP - that's what DHCPv6 is for: DHCP and DHCPv6 are not compatible.

As of turning IPv6 off or not: If you don't need it and your ISP doesn't provide it yet, turn it off *but prepare for its introduction*. This includes to remove/redesign everything that relies explicitly on legacy IP, such as hard coded IP addresses or using broadcast.

Apropos turning IPv6 off: beware that for instance Microsoft considers IPv6 an integral part of the operating system, so turning IPv6 off there might affect the support you get from them.

Answer (score 0):

What I do personally on particular servers where I don't want `IPv6`:

- disable all outgoing/incoming traffic via `ip6tables`
- only enable *loopback*

In `sysctl.conf`, `IPv6` allowed internal:

- `net.ipv4.ip_forward=1`
- `net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=0`
- `net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6=0`

Create the file `/etc/iptables/rules.v6` with:

```
*filter
:INPUT DROP [3:216]
:FORWARD DROP [0:0]
:OUTPUT DROP [0:0]
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
```

Apply with:

```
ip6tables-restore < /etc/iptables/rules.v6
```

On Debian, need `iptables-persistent` package.

You can check the rules with:

```
ip6tables -L -nvx
```

Enabling `IPv6` on the *loopback* allow most applications to run, that can breaks some if you don't allow it. `xrdp` by example.